# Change value of each row of dataframe column with a function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function which appends a "0" to the from of a value if that value is only 1 char in length:

```
myFormat <- function(v) {
  if(nchar(v) == 1){
    paste0("0",v)
  }
  else
    as.character(v)
}
```

I have a dataframe `DF` with a column named `A` of type character that looks like:

```
A
3
12
5
10
1
...
```

After running `myFormat()`, column `A` should look like:

```
A
03
12
05
01
...
```

I tried:  `DF$A <- lapply(DF$A, weekFormat(DF$A))`  but am getting errors.

I also tried: `mutate(DF, newCol = myFormat(A))`  but get error there saying only first element will be used.

Also tried: `cbind(DF, lapply(DF$A, wmyFormat)`  but this adds many new columns.

Whats going wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Use the basic apply instead, `data.frame(A = apply(DF, 1, myFormat))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be easily done using `sprintf`.  Using @nrussell's data

```
DF$A <- sprintf("%02d", DF$A)
DF$A
#[1] "03" "12" "05" "10" "01"
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to make a function to do this.  Just use sprintf.

```
DF$A<-sprintf("%02d",DF$A)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `weekFormat` is supposed to be `myFormat` of vice versa. This is what you want

```
DF$A <- unlist(lapply(DF$A, myFormat))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `sapply` instead of `lapply`:

```
DF <- data.frame(A=c(3,12,5,10,1))
> DF
   A
1  3
2 12
3  5
4 10
5  1
##
DF$A <- sapply(DF$A, myFormat)
> DF
   A
1 03
2 12
3 05
4 10
5 01
```

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because `if` is not vectorized, and uses only the first element.  `sprintf` is the best answer, IMO. But to fix your error, try `ifelse` in your function.

```
ifelse(nchar(x) == 1, paste0("0", x), x)
# [1] "03" "12" "05" "10" "01"
```

You can also use a vector subset in your function.  That way it can be used nicely with `lapply`

```
myFormat <- function(v) {
    w <- which(nchar(v) == 1)
    v[w] <- paste0("0", v[w])   
    v
}
lapply(DF, myFormat)
# $A
# [1] "03" "12" "05" "10" "01"
```

But `sprintf` is definitely better for what you are doing.